# Rational solutions of equations of the form $y^2 x = f(x)$

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations

Let $k$ be any number field, and suppose we want to study the $k$-rational points on 
$$y^2 x = f(x),$$ where $f$ is a polynomial of degree greater or equal than 3. In other words, $y^2 x = f(x)$ is a sort of twisted elliptic or hyperelliptic curve. 
**Question:** What are the techniques available to tackle equations like $y^2 x = f(x)$?

Comment: Substitute $z=yx$, then the rational points with $x\ne 0$ correspond to rational points of $z^2=xf(x)$.

Comment: I should have thought of that. Thanks!